# Parametrized SQL query returns no results, String formatted query returns correct results

Tags: c#, sql, .net, t-sql

I have an SQL table from which I'm trying to search for orders that match a dynamic, user-provided search string, then fill the OrderDataTable with the results. Here is the C# code:

```
CmdString = "SELECT * FROM SQL_TABLE WHERE (CHARINDEX('@searchstring', ordernumber) > 0 OR CHARINDEX('@searchstring', customername) > 0)"

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchstring", OrderDisplayViewModel.SearchString);

        comm.CommandText = CmdString;

        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
        {
            using (DataTable tempdatatable = new DataTable())
            {
                sda.Fill(tempdatatable);
                OrderDataTable.Merge(tempdatatable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This returns no results even for queries I've run in SSMS that return numerous results. Additionally, when I remove the parametrization and replace @searchstring with the text from the search box, the query functions correctly. I'd prefer not to leave the application that open to injection but I can't figure out what's wrong with the way I'm using parameters.

Comment: I think single quotes kill your parameterized query. That's why your SQL sees it as a _string literal_, not parameter.

Comment: have you debugged it and hovered over OrderDisplayViewModel.SearchString?

Comment: @Marc got it 11 seconds before you. That was exactly it - those single quotes are so invisible next to double quotes that I just glazed right over them. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean:

```
CHARINDEX(@searchstring, ordernumber)
```

not

```
CHARINDEX('@searchstring', ordernumber)
```

(likewise `customername`)

`@searchstring` is the parameter; `'@searchstring'` is a literal string that contains the 13 characters starting in `@` and ending in `g`.